# Test and Feedback Chrome extension, how to change Server URL?

Tags: azure-devops

I work for a Microsoft D365 partner and have installed the Test and feedback extension and linked it to one of our DevOps accounts.  I also work with a client who has DevOps, however I'm unable to change the connection settings so I can work in their DevOps account.  All of the connection settings are grayed out.

The connection settings are grayed out, I haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are **Disconnect** link in setting: [Exploratory testing with the Test & Feedback extension in Connected mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/connected-mode-exploratory-testing?view=azure-devops)

[image]

If there isn't, you may try to uninstall, then reinstall it or try it with other browsers.

Comment: In place of the "Disconnect" I instead have a button labeled "Repair", which doesn't seem to do anything when clicked.

Comment: @MichaelMcCardle Have you tried to re-install this extension? What's the result if you try it with other browsers?